# Preventing package from changing footer

Tags: header-footer, packages, fancyhdr

I'm fairly unexperienced with LaTeX, but I'm currently working on a cookbook using the package `xcookybooky`.
I have made a number of modifications to the design to fit my own needs, but I'm currently stuck with a little problem. I want each page to have a footer that describes the current section, subsection and page. Unfortunately it seems that xcookybooky is renewing the  command for changing to footer in its code with no way of modification. The code can be seen in the [documentation](https://mirror.easyname.at/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcookybooky/xcookybooky.pdf) in section 6.12.

```
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]
{%
\markright{\MakeUppercase{\thesection.\ #1}}
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}
{%
0.5pt
}
\fancyhf{}
\if@twoside
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\rightmark}
\else
\fancyfoot[R]{\textbf{\thepage}}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\fi
\fancyhead[C]{\@newpagehint{head}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\@newpagehint{foot}}
```

Is there a way to ignore / manually overwrite this behaviour, so I can customize the content of the footer to my liking?

Comment: What happens if you add your own `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` commands after `\usepackage{xcokkybooky}`?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP solved his problem AND the way the question is stated and coded seems to be a bit too general for people running into a similar problem (can‘t be reproduced both as problem and solution).

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it thanks to gernot's comment! I'm not specifically overwriting any behaviour but I found which mistake I personally made.

I have each recipe as a individual .tex files. I just noticed that in the template those .tex files have a `\thispagestyle{plain}`. Removing it solves the problem and I can set my own fancy footer.

Comment: Great. Can you please add or at least sketch your changes on code level, briefly? Might be easier to grasp for future readers.